# C++11 guarantee no concurrent calls

Tags: c++11

Are `std::mutex` and `std::unique_ptr` sufficient to guarantee that there will be no concurrent calls to an object? In the following code snippet will `Object` not have any concurrent calls?

```
class Example {
public:
std::mutex Mutex;
Example(){...
};
//
private:
static std::unique_ptr<Object> Mutex;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you would have to lock and unlock the `mutex`, when you need it. Just the existance of a mutex in no guarantee. Also a `unique_ptr` cannot change this!

mutex example is in the reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Answer (score 3):

Const however does now guarantee that nothing can change your object at the same time than you are using the const.
**This obviously suppose you use a well coded object (like STL containers) and that no one tried to work around the compiler checks**.

See : http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/

Comment: This is a dangerous statement. `const` only means thread-safe if the implementation follows some rules. In terms of the standard, `const` indeed is interchangable with thread-safety, but it doesn't mean you can't abuse that. Take this wrapper of a vector as a stupid example of how to do it wrong: http://ideone.com/ldcGfv  So `const` may be used as an indicator for thread-safety, but not a guarantee. It's the same as with the OPs thought on "the presence of a mutex is enough". The presence of `const` isn't enough. Protect it.

Comment: Yes I mean const on an STDLib or well coded const function. You can always do bad. :)

Comment: @stefan any notes on which implementations of const are thread safe?

Comment: @pyCthon None. none whatsoever. The standard library is built for performance, so thread-safety is extremely rare in this code. In the code of someone else: Check and double check. If in any doubt, protect it with your own mutex. If the developer doesn't explicitely say "it's thread-safe" and you're uncertain about any method, make it thread-safe yourself. You can't make anything thread-safe by adding `const`, even though it may compile.

Comment: I agree there was no thread safety before c++11, but since getting on a STL container guarantee that during the time of the get function the container itself will not change. But it is true that most of the STL function is not based on thread safety. **For performance and thread safety look for PPL, TBB, concurrent_queu of boost for instance**

Comment: @dzada thanks i was actually looking into hpx over c++11 and boost.

Answer (score 0):

unique_ptr is mainly related with resources management and RAII idiom. You don't need to use unique_ptr to achieve thread safety even in some scenarios it may prove useful. However, the example that you provided is a bit unusual, you used the identifier Mutex twice to indicate a std::mutex and a std::unique_ptr.

I suggest to get some good books on C++ before to dwelve in more complex topics like concurrency and resources management.

This nice article of Diego Dagum explains what is new regarding concurency in C++11
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852594.aspx

And an article about unique_ptr:
http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708